# handling sessions on every page of website

Tags: asp.net, session, architecture, webforms

I have a data driven website and the current users Id gets stored in Session["UserId"].So all the data that shows up in almost all the pages is user specific.and when a user is using the site anonymously,it is a different set of results that i show and has nothing to do with the UserId.

My problem is I have to check if the Session["UserId"] is not null at every line where I am using Session["UserId"] and i somehow feel that it is not the right way to do it.

Is there a way where I can check if the Session is not null on page_load? If my session turns out to be null, how do i handle it? the page won't even load at all.

I hope i was able to explain

Answer (score 1):

Instead of check session on every of your pages, put the session control in a base class and make all your pages extends this class. Every time your page inits the `Page_Init` base method will check if user is authenticated. If it's not authenticated the method will throw an exception that will be catched by `Page_Error` method. This method will clear session resources and redirect to Default page.

Make a hyerarchical classes for session control:

```
public class UserSession { }
public class AnonymousSession : UserSession {}
```

On your Page Logon put the `UserId` on the session based on logon type:

```
bool isAnon = GetAnonymous(); // Check form page if login is anonymously
UserSession user;
if(isAnon)
  user = new AnonymousSession();
else
   user = new UserSession();
Session.Contents.Add("UserId", user);
```

Set a property in `PageBase` named `Anonymously` that tells you if user has entered anonymously, and use it in your pages to set the set results of each of your pages:

```
public class PageBase: System.Web.Ui.Page
{
   // Check here if session type is anonymous
   protected bool Anonymously 
   {
      get
      {
           return (UserSession)Session.Contents["UserId"] is AnonymousSession;
      }
   }

   protected void Page_Init(object Sender,System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        var user = (UserSession)Session.Contents["UserId"];
        if (user == null) 
        { 
            throw new SessionException();
        } 
    }


    protected void Page_Error(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
         Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
         Server.ClearError();
         if(ex is SessionException)
         {
            Context.Session.Clear();
            Context.Session.Abandon();
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Server.Transfer("Default.aspx", true);
         }
    }
}
```